# S3 not serving media files to Django heroku app

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-storage

Good night fellas, I'm trying to setup a app with django on Heroku using S3 as a server for my javascript and my stylesheet. Following some posts, I configured a bucket on S3 and configured my env vars into heroku. Then in my settings file I have something like this

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',        
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'apuh',
    'storages',
)

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
```

STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

When I run my app, it crashes with this error:

```
Error: No module named storages
```

I installed django_storages with pip install django_storages. It's installed on my enviroment. If I comment the 'storages' line it wont load any of the files from the bucket, I guess that the request doesn't send the propers tokens for authentication.

So, my question is, what I'm doing wrong. I have checked questions and questions but looks like I'm missing something big.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe adding these would help?

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

and yes installing [boto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto) aswell

and then run pip freeze > requirements.txt just to make sure if all your dependencies are up to date

I hope it helps

Comment: I have installed boto (pip install boto), I ran pip freeze. My settings lacks of the default_file_storage. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I setted up everything with a loose permissions. Now it works. thanks